# How do I enable JSP support in Jetty 8 on Debian Wheezy?

Tags: jetty, debian

I have a Debian Wheezy server and I'd like to use Jetty to deploy Java web applications as .war files. I'm attempting to configure Jetty to properly display a basic jsp page so that I can assume I have a working Jetty server configuration before getting too far. However, I'm having some issues configuring JSP support and not much luck finding Debian-specific documentation.

I've installed Jetty 8 via the `jetty8` and `libjetty8-java` packages and created an application via IntelliJ IDEA; the resulting .war contains just an index.jsp and a WEB-INF/web.xml file. The web.xml file contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
</web-app>
```

The index.jsp file contains this:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head><title>Test</title></head>
  <body>Test</body>
</html>
```

Nothing too fancy there. I then enabled JSP support in Jetty by changing `JETTY_ARGS` in `/etc/default/jetty8` to `OPTIONS=default,jsp`, placed the .war in `$JETTY_HOME/webapps`, and restarted the Jetty server.

Attempting to load the page failed and left this error in the logs:

```
2013-03-22 22:39:38.914:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.3.v20120416
2013-03-22 22:39:39.034:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{,file:/var    /lib/jetty8/webapps/root/},file:/var/lib/jetty8/webapps/root/
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[...snip...]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:602)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:82)
Caused by:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/PeriodicEventListener
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
[...snip...]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:602)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:82)
```

This led me to include `tomcat-api.jar` in `$JETTY_HOME/lib/ext`, which then led me to include `tomcat-juli.jar` (to correct a NoClassDefFoundError for `org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory`), and finally `tomcat-jasper-el.jar` (to correct a NoClassDefFoundError for `org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl`).

My current JSP-related jars in my classpath look like this:

```
/usr/share/jetty8/lib$ ls -l jsp
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Jun 25  2012 javax.el.jar -> ../../../java/el-api-2.2.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jun 25  2012 javax.servlet.jsp.jar -> ../../../java/jsp-api-2.2.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Jun 25  2012 javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar -> ../../../java/jstl1.1.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jun 25  2012 org.apache.jasper.jar -> ../../../java/tomcat-jasper.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Jun 25  2012 org.apache.taglibs.standard.jar -> ../../../java/standard.jar
/usr/share/jetty8/lib$ ls -l ext
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Mar 23 09:59 tomcat-api.jar -> ../../../java/tomcat-api.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Mar 23 09:45 tomcat-jasper-el.jar -> ../../../java/tomcat-jasper-el.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Mar 23 09:43 tomcat-juli.jar -> ../../../java/tomcat-juli.jar
```

The jars in the `jsp` directory are those provided by the default Jetty install, while I have added mine to `ext`.

My current error is this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager set in ServletContext
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.InstanceManagerFactory.getInstanceManager(InstanceManagerFactory.java:35)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:171)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:598)
[...snip...]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Based on research, it seems like this could occur if I included tomcat libraries in my .war, but I don't. I'm not entirely sure where to proceed from here, and I'm not having any luck finding documentation covering this.

Has anyone had success taking Jetty 8 in Debian Wheezy and enabling JSP or have any ideas where I may have gone wrong with attempting to?

Comment: Did you read [this page on the Jetty Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JSP)?  Just asking as the default process to enable JSP looks quite straightforward and doesn't involve scraping jars together from all over the place?

Comment: I did read that page, yes. Based on that, it looked like it *should* just work when I enabled the jsp option, as webdefault.xml is already configured correctly. I'm suspecting there is some subtle breakage in the Debian packaging...

Answer (score 1):

I was configuring servlet annotations with jetty8/Ubuntu 12.10 on AWS, and had a similar problem. Well, at least up to the PeriodicEventListener NCDFE/CNF exception -- after that point, unlike you, I didn't have the persistence to start adding random Tomcat JARs. ;-)

In my case, the problem was resolved by narrowing down the OPTIONS spec in start.config. I had lazily used "All", which should of course be legal but was wider than strictly required. Changing the spec to "annotations,plus,default,*" did the trick. I haven't examined exactly why, but I assume one of the superfluous JARs loaded by "All" had an unresolved dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get it working after quite a few steps:

- Make sure the following packages are installed: libtomcat6-java,
  libecj-java, libjstl1.1-java, libservlet3.0-java and obviously jetty8.
- Create a new directory in /usr/share/jetty8/lib/abc. Choose the name of the 'abc' directory wisely, it seems to have critical impact. Jetty/Debian somehow sorts the classpath or directory names alphabetically.
- Add the following symlinks in your 'abc' directory:

-

```
ecj.jar -> ../../../java/ecj.jar
jasper-el.jar -> ../../../java/jasper-el.jar
jasper.jar -> ../../../java/jasper.jar
jstl1.1.jar -> ../../../java/jstl1.1.jar
tomcat-el-api-2.2.jar -> ../../../java/tomcat-el-api-2.2.jar
tomcat-jsp-api-2.2.jar -> ../../../java/tomcat-jsp-api-2.2.jar
tomcat-juli.jar -> ../../../java/tomcat-juli.jar
```

- Configure jetty to use the new lib directory by adding the following line to /etc/default/jetty8

  JETTY_ARGS="OPTIONS=default,abc"
- Start jetty8

Inspiration came from this post by James Page: https://lists.debian.org/debian-java/2012/05/msg00132.html